# Show user based on subdomain

Tags: 8, domain-access

Im using [Domains Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) to create a subdomain and already created all the virtualhosts, so that one is working.

Is it possible to show a user based on domain name?

Im creating a view, and i need to show for example:

**lucas.site.com** and show user **lucas**.

I have tried by adding contextual filter: User ID context on route.
But it doesn't take effect, it looks in **lucas.site.com/lucas** maybe im missing something?

Comment: You can try this https://www.drupal.org/project/user_field_value  in your contextual filter  or really contextual filters don't really look for the domain or subdomain  .. So you want to display the domain that user belongs to ?? please include more info on the view you are creating could you just use a custom text field and a twig replacement ?

Comment: Thank you, already done with a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Reply to my self:

I have created a custom Controller that get the user from db based on the domain, i get the subdomain using this:

```
$subdomain = substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.') > 1 ? substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.')) : '';
```

Not sure if its the best.

Then i compare to the user on db:

```
$result = \Drupal::database()->select('user_data', 'n')
            ->fields('n', array('id', 'user_domain', 'user_email'))
            ->condition('n.user_domain', $subdomain)
            ->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('id');
```

First you need to create a install schema with the domain created so you can fetch this.

Then loading by user email:

```
$user = user_load_by_mail($userEmail);
```

and pass the variable to the Twig.
Not sure if its the best way.